# Sorted columns of ascending and descending date order

Tags: python, html, css, mysql

I need to sort some columns in a webpage, but i don't know where the problem is, I'm barely new to web development so I need so much help. I want to order the columns by date order (asc or desc), but there's a problem with this because the order is all wrong. I was searching and maybe it is a problem with the component (front) because it doesn't understand the dynamism of the columns.

I have already tried changing these lines:

```
 order = None
    dir = True
    if request.GET.get("[order][0][column]"):
        order = request.GET.get("[order][0][column]")
    if request.GET.get("[order][0][dir]"):
        if request.GET.get("[order][0][dir]") == "asc":
            dir = True
        else:
            dir = False

    start = 0
    if request.GET.get("start"):
        start = int(request.GET.get("start"))
    if order:
        result = sorted(result, key=lambda item: item[int(order)], reverse=dir)
```

But it doesn't change anything, if the problem comes from the component, it will be helpful if someone helps me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this question is really missing more information,
it seems like you are using a python web framework of some sort is it Django?

which variable are you trying to sort? is it order?

then you have to pass order in the sort function instead of:

```
result = sorted(result, key=lambda item: item[int(order)], reverse=dir)
```

write:

```
result = sorted(order, key=lambda item: item[int(order)], reverse=dir)
```

what is the structure of order? is it a dictionary a list?

additionally i can't see the end of your function are you returning result? 
please copy all the code possible so i can better understand and help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes I'm using Django. I want to sort ```result```, the code is very long, can I send it to you private?

Comment: @MemoZC you can uploade your code to a code sandbox like https://pyfiddle.io/ and send the link here

Comment: @MemoZC i would start by mocking the object you want to sort and try sorting it inside the sandbox

Comment: https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/9c6155db-8979-4e99-8b3b-f5fbd221deee/?i=true

Comment: @MemoZC can you add in line 73 `print result` run your code and paste the result here?